# GAE - processing external URI

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

I am trying to process URIs on GAE flexible, specifically I am processing pdf files through `pdf2image`.
Whenever I use the URI on pdf2image's `convert_from_path`, GAE throws

> File not Found

, but if I do the same process on my local machine it is executed with no errors.
Should I set something up on Google App Engine to allow it?

Comment: Can you post the code to see how you were retrieving this file? Thank you!!! (Or if Alex answer is working just accept it and we will use his example code.)

Comment: Alex's answer solved it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

where is this pdf?

Your title says 'external URI' but `pdf2image`'s docs for `convert_from_path` seems to indicate that this file is sitting in your code.

If the file is indeed sitting in your project code and getting deployed with your project, try using this to convert a relative path to an absolute one:

```
curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
images = convert_from_path(curr_dir+'/my/relative/path/example.pdf')
```

**Edit:**

For pdfs on GCS, I would handle the download from gcs separately and then use `convert_from_bytes` instead of `convert_from_path`

You'd setup your connection to GCS like this:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage

Use this function to get the GCS blob:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.get_blob

And then use this function to actually download the bytes:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_string

So something like this:

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('/path/to/blob.pdf')
bytes = blob.download_as_string()
images = convert_from_bytes(bytes)
```

Comment: It is hosted on google storage. And it is the same file that is converted normally on my local machine (using the same URI).

Comment: updated my answer for a pdf on GCS. Also, it looks like `pdf2image` is just a python wrapper to the bash command `pdftoppm`. Did you get that setup on your GAE flex environment?